# Ubuntu 19.04 Gnome High CPU Usage When Resizing or Moving Windows

Tags: drivers, 18.04, gnome, graphics, amd-graphics

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 and noticed that the UI was very laggy, and I could hear my CPU fan spinning up a lot more than usual.

I upgraded to 19.04 since the release notes indicated performance improvements, however I'm still seeing the same issue.

Issue:
Resizing or moving windows around on screen causes CPU usage to spike very high, and for the UI to become very choppy.

Hardware:

- CPU: AMD® Phenom(tm) II x4 955
- GPU: AMD® Radeon 4850 (Rv770)

I have a dedicated GPU in my desktop, however, I suspect that since my GPU is very old, it's not being used to accelerate the drawing of the gnome UI.

Is there a way to confirm that I have the correct driver for my GPU, and whether hardware acceleration is supported / working?

Comment: I do not know if it will be the same problem, but when doing login it also consumes a lot of CPU. The same thing happens when selecting files to upload them through the browser.